# Counting points space shooter unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, counting

my code in GameController is :

```
public void AddScore(int newscore) 
{
    score += newscore;
    UpdateScore();
 }

void UpdateScore() 
{
    scoreText.text = "score " + score;
}
```

and my code in destroyByContact :

```
public GameController gameController;

void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{
    if (other.tag =="boundary")
     { 
        return; 
     }
    Instantiate(explosion, transform.position, transform.rotation);
    if (other.tag == "player")
    {
        Instantiate(playerexplosion, other.transform.position, other.transform.rotation);
    }
    gameController.AddScore(scoreValue);
    Destroy(other.gameObject);
    Destroy(gameObject);
}
```

and unity display this error :
error CS1061: Type `GameController' does not contain a definition for`AddScore' and no extension method `AddScore' of type`GameController' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Where is `scoreValue` defined? Update the code in your question

Comment: Please show us the signature of how your GameController class is defined. Is GameController a base class? If so, then you'll need to cast your controller to the appropriate one with the AddScore method defined, if that's a specific method rather than a generic one to all GameControllers.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about your actual destroyByContact class. But I think you might be not declaring the object or referencing it.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class destroyByContact : MonoBehaviour {

public GameObject explosion;
public GameObject playerExplosion;
public int scoreValue;

private GameController gameController;

void Start()
{
    GameObject gameControllerObject = GameObject.FindWithTag("GameController");
    if (gameControllerObject != null)
    {
        gameController = gameControllerObject.GetComponent<GameController>();
    }
    if (gameController == null)
    {
        Debug.Log("Cannot find 'GameController' script");
    }
}

void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{
    if (other.CompareTag("boundary"))
    {
        return;
    }

    if (explosion != null)
    {
        Instantiate(explosion, transform.position, transform.rotation);
    }

    if (other.tag == "Player")
    {
        Instantiate(playerExplosion, other.transform.position, other.transform.rotation);
        gameController.GameOver();
    }

    gameController.AddScore(scoreValue);
    Destroy(other.gameObject);
    Destroy(gameObject);
}
```

}

Please note that code in

**start()**

tries to get the reference of the **GameController** script & If the script is not referred it will print the following log.